# PHP mail with chunked CSV attachment causing double newline error

Tags: php, email, csv, chunked-encoding

I try to send a CSV file using PHP mail. This is the version that causes double newline ERROR (gotten from server error logs):

```
$content = base64_encode($content);
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
if (!mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
}
```

while when I remove the "chunk_split", it causes no error, but recipient mail server does not accept it (i.e. it does not appear neither in Inbox nor in Spam).

Notice: the "double newline error" code used to work on previous hosting but fails to work on new one.

Comment: seriously, don't use PHP's `mail()` function. It's so full of gotchas it's not funny. Use a decent mailer class like [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). You'll save yourself a *lot* of headaches.